# Your device isn't compatible with this version :Can install apk manually in that device

Tags: android, device, compatibility

I have built one android application and uploaded in playstore. Few devices most probably which are not having gps are not able to download from playstore. Playstore saying "your device isn't compatible with this version".

I am using 
the following permission and features

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

I didn't make the feature required=true, so far I know if don't mention required=true then it will not prevent devices to download which are not having such features.

For your information, manually I am able to install the apk to the same device. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: try to add `required=false` in uses-feature of gps.

Comment: Thanks.I am trying .For the sake of interest If don't mention it as false is it possible to install in those devices manually? Actually I am able to install manually.

Comment: What do you mean by **not having GPS** ? Android devices exist without GPS?

Comment: @AshwinMothilal. YES

Comment: Can you please give me a link of android device like that.

Comment: lot of devices are without gps but location feature is there.I am working for a client in South Africa. I faced it.

Comment: Thanks @DheerubhaiBansal. It Worked.